# Azure DevOps 2019 On-premises: How can I enable feature preview?

Tags: azure, server, devops

How can I enable Feature preview in Azure DevOps 2019 on-premises?

I have installed the bellow extension and one of its most important functionalities is: "Portofolio Plans (Preview)". I can not access this functionality from Boards menu and I do believe it has something to do with it being on "preview" mode.

Please do not suggest updating Azure DevOps to 2020 since this is not a possibility for me and my team at the momement.

Thank you!